# Tengo que editar datos de mi base de datos pero para eso tengo que saber la id de la categoría

Tags: mysql, c#

Este es código y el error es en el segundo select

```
Update producto set PrecioVenta="4590", 

PrecioCompra="3750", 

Nombre="Carburador 28mm", 

Stock="12",

Marca="Mikuni",

Descripcion="Moto Suzuki DR-Z400 Kawasaki KLX", 

NomFoto ="carburador.png",

(select IDCat from categoria where NombreCat ="Otros") where CodigoProducto = "34535453";
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que es ese select ahi en el medio?

Comment: Qué campo establece `(select IDCat from categoria where NombreCat ="Otros")`?

Comment: mejora un poco la pregunta

Comment: Es un programa en C# ese es el código sql para editar, en el programa se establecen todos esos campos y se eligue una categoría para el producto. Hay una tabla que relaciona los productos con id de categoría, bueno el campo en el programa selecciona el nombre de la categoría pero en la tabla de mysql está la IdCat sería id categoría. En el código sql necesito conseguir la IdCat con el nombre establecido por el usuario del programa. PERDÓN NO SE EXPLICARME